# Getting live real time signals from Emotiv EPOC in MatLab

Tags: matlab

I need to make MatLab show real time signals from Emotiv EPOC.
I used eeglogger toolkit. I created path for that toolkit in matlab, added the path in command by using addpath command. And here is the error which I got.

```
Warning: Message from C preprocessor:
lcc preprocessor error: C:\Program Files\Emotiv Research Edition SDK v2.0.0.20\doc\examples_Matlab\edk.h:17 Could not find include
file <string>
lcc preprocessor error: C:\Program Files\Emotiv Research Edition SDK v2.0.0.20\doc\examples_Matlab\edk.h:18 Could not find include
file <sstream>

> In loadlibrary at 371
  In eeglogger at 84
Warning: 'EXP_SENSITIVITY}EE_ExpressivThreshold_t;typedefenumEE_ExpressivTrainingControl_enum{EXP_NONE=0'
 exceeds MATLAB's maximum name length of 63 characters and has been truncated to
 'EXP_SENSITIVITY}EE_ExpressivThreshold_t;typedefenumEE_Expressiv'. 
> In edk_proto at 10
  In loadlibrary at 432
  In eeglogger at 84
Error loading library intermediate output follows.
The actual error is at the end of this output.
*********


No match found for enum value expression EE_ExpressivAlgo_t in 0x0800}EE_ExpressivAlgo_t;typedefenumEE_AffectivAlgo_enum{AFF_EXCITEMENT=0x0001 expression ignored.
Found on line 444 of input from line 653 of file C:\Program Files\Emotiv Research Edition SDK v2.0.0.20\doc\examples_Matlab\EmoStateDLL.h


No match found for enum value expression EE_AffectivAlgo_t in 0x0010}EE_AffectivAlgo_t;typedefenumEE_CognitivAction_enum{COG_NEUTRAL=0x0001 expression ignored.
Found on line 444 of input from line 653 of file C:\Program Files\Emotiv Research Edition SDK v2.0.0.20\doc\examples_Matlab\EmoStateDLL.h


No match found for enum value expression EE_CognitivAction_t in 0x2000}EE_CognitivAction_t;typedefenumEE_SignalStrength_enum{NO_SIGNAL=0 expression ignored.
Found on line 444 of input from line 653 of file C:\Program Files\Emotiv Research Edition SDK v2.0.0.20\doc\examples_Matlab\EmoStateDLL.h


No match found for enum value expression EE_Event_t in 16|32|64|128|256|512|1024}EE_Event_t;typedefenumEE_ExpressivEvent_enum{EE_ExpressivNoEvent=0 expression ignored.
Found on line 1097 of input from line 1165 of file C:\Program Files\Emotiv Research Edition SDK v2.0.0.20\doc\examples_Matlab\edk.h
*********
??? Error using ==> loadlibrary at 477
There was an error running the loader mfile.  Use the mfilename option
to produce a file that you can debug and fix if needed.  Please report
this error to the MathWorks so we can improve this function.


Error in ==> eeglogger at 84
    [nf, w] = loadlibrary('edk','edk');

Caused by:
    Error using ==> struct
    Invalid field name "EXP_SENSITIVITY}EE_ExpressivThreshold_t;typedefenumEE_Expressiv"
```

How can I make eeglogger to recognize files?
Any leads?
TIA :)